# How can I block threads until prime is found, unblock it, then have them wait until next prime?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am writing a multithreaded Sieve of Eratosthenes where I have to use pthreads.  I'm pretty sure the way to do this is to use mutexes and cond_waits.  I create 4 threads in the beginning of the program, and then I have to force them to wait until the Sieve of Eratosthenes finds a prime number.  Then I have to unblock the threads so they can mark down every iteration of that prime within the bit array.  Then, they have to block again and wait for the next prime, until the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm exhausts itself of new numbers.

This is the code from my threaded function:

```
while(!doneFlag){
        printf("Thread wile loop\n");
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &lock);

        startingPosition = (double)(maxNum/numThreads) * i;
        endingPosition = (double)(maxNum/numThreads) * (i+1)-1;
        if(i == numThreads-1){
            endingPosition = maxNum;
        } 
... Until the end of the function ... 
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
return (void*)0;
```

doneFlag is a flag that I set to 1 when the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm finishes with all the numbers.  I was hoping that the while loop, with the cond_wait() function would cause the threads to wait for input (as long as there was input left to give)

Here is the Sieve portion in the main() function:

```
while(outerCounter < sqrt(maxNum)){
    //searching numbers above the current for prime numbers
    //printf("Sieve While\n");
    for(innerCounter = outerCounter+1; innerCounter <= maxNum; innerCounter++){
        //not composite
        //printf("Sieve for\n");
        if(composite[innerCounter] == 0){

            printf("Prime found: %d\n", innerCounter);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

            outerCounter = innerCounter;
            numPrimes++;

        }
    }
}
doneFlag = 1;
```

Somehow, the composite numbers aren't being marked as composite (though a couple are).  I assume because it has something to do with a race condition with the main() function, how it keeps finding more primes while the threads are still running in the background, thereby changing the prime number while the threads are still working.

How can I fix this?  Are my locks/cond_wait set up properly?  I am having a really hard time finding resources for this online.

Thanks!

Edit: I also want to make sure that each of my threads can run the function concurrently (The function is what marks elements in the array as composite).  Maybe mutexes aren't a good idea in my thread function since I want them to run together? (Each thread takes a different segment of the array)

Comment: One comment is that you are using the same mutex for locking but mentioned 4 threads to be run in parallel. This can be done with a counting semaphore with value 4. Otherwise, only one thread can run at the same time at max.

Answer (score 1):

Fayyazkl said it first. Use a counting semaphore instead of a muted. Look up producer/consumer, cause that's the problem you're solving!

So, I'm not familiar with the algorithm that you're using but I tried to understand so I could give a bit more help. I assume each new prime is a new job?

Whatever the case, you need your main loop to produce jobs that are self contained so that a job thread can pull a new job from the job queue and have all of the information that it needs. If the job is just the new prime number, then add the new prime number to a queue and post the counting semaphore.(remember that the queue needs synchronization though)

The threads will first pend on the counting semaphore. When the semaphore becomes signalled, a thread will wake up and fetch the job that was placed in the queue before the sem was signalled. Then the thread will process the job and post the result.

I think your problem is that you don't have a centralized way of generating new jobs with explicit job parameters, so that two or more threads are waking up and getting the same job, or none are.

Comment: I wasn't aware semaphores could be shared by threads.  If I want to get threads to run at the same time using semaphores, am I going to have to define "thread number" number of semaphores?

Comment: Nope. Use one semaphore, and initialize it to the number of 'produced' jobs. Every time a thread wants a new job, it decrements the semaphore by 1. If there are no jobs, then that thread will go on sleep until the job producer produces a new job. The process of decrementing/pending a semaphore is atomic and blocking and will always return with ownership of one of the jobs. (unless it returns a failure code).